# unable to download grunt, yeoman, or bower

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting the following error for grunt, yeoman and bower:

```
Drews-iMac:~ drewjocham$ npm install -g grunt-cli
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/drewjocham/.npm/grunt-cli/0.1.13/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/drewjocham/npm-debug.log
```

I have tried sudo but that doesn't work either. I have tried all of the following commands in my mac terminal:

Bower   `npm install -g bower`

Yeoman `npm install -g yo`

Grunt `npm install -g grunt-cli`

Nodejs `npm -version` is 2.7.4

Answer (score 3):

You should try "sudo npm install ...":

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

It seems to be a permission issue during installation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the NPM "fixing permissions" documentation page (there's even a video!): https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions